Tableless model in Rails 7
I am upgrading a Rails app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 7 (don't ask!!). There is a tableless model that was using this gist, but it's no longer working. It looks like the suggestions here no longer work either. Does anyone have a working solution?
I have tried to ActiveModel:API but I need to support associations.

ActiveModel::API
Use ActiveModel::API. It's the official module from the Rails core team for this purpose. You're aware of it I know, you've tried it.
But, it doesn't support assocations?
True. Implement these yourself in your stateless models.
It can be very simple, depending on how much these stateless models are used in your legacy application. Just ensure that all the messages called on your stateless models are defined.
E.G.
class Person
  def pets
    @pets ||= []
  end
end

class Pet
end

bob = Person.new
dog_1 = Pet.new
bob.pets << dog_1

There is advantage to using stateless models, it's a familiar set of abstractions that can make maintenance of your legacy application cheaper.
Rails doesn't support this associations for a reason. Associations between models are entirely coupled to SQL datastores. You cannot have one without the other. As they're a Ruby representation of primary and foreign keys in SQL.
So if you want this, you'll have to write a simple version of it.
Because in truth it's an uncommon approach.

I've considered implementing associations myself but I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for (to help with fields_for) and that is explicitly checking for associations. I have ended up creating a model despite there not being much use for it, but maybe I should look at using fields_for without accepts_nested_attributes_for.
